# Swift - Array won't .append(data) in closure

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I'm sure I miss something obvious.

Using Parse Server I want to fill some data from a request into a dictionary.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (books, error) in
            guard (books != nil) else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            for book in books! {
                print("\n\n\(book)")  //#1 Got some book

                if let coverString = book["cover"] {
                    print("coverString OK : \(coverString)") //#2 got a valid String
                    self.bookImages.append(coverString as? String)
                } else {
                    print("coverString nil")
                    self.bookImages.append(nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

If I : `print("Tableau image: \(bookImages)\n")` I got nothing in my `var bookImages = [String?]()` even if I got something inside `coverString` #2.

but if I .append("foobar") anywhere else (to try) except in the closure my dictionary is not empty.

Why this strange magic ?

Comment: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous operation. So your array (`.append` is for arrays, not dictionaries) is probably populated correctly but you are probably looking at it when it's not populated *yet*.

Comment: Yes sorry, I need a coffee, an array you are right. Also I didn't think about it but you are probably right about the async method. Hum? But I have no idea how to manage this. here a gist of my file : gist.github.com/gfelot/70af1dd940d605b47578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous operation.

So your array (`.append` is for arrays, not dictionaries) is probably populated correctly but you are looking at it when it's not populated *yet*.

You will see the results if you put your `print` statements *inside* the closure.

And you should also reload the TableView there, but with redispatching it to the main thread.

Example:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (books, error) in
    guard (books != nil) else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    for book in books! {

        if let coverString = book["cover"] {
            print("coverString OK : \(coverString)")
            self.bookImages.append(coverString as? String)
        } else {
            print("coverString nil")
            self.bookImages.append(nil)
        }

        if let titleString = book["title"] {
            print("titleString OK : \(titleString)")
            self.bookTitle.append(titleString as? String)
        } else {
            print("titleString nil")
            self.bookTitle.append("No Title")
        }
    }

    print("Tableau image2: \(self.bookImages)\n")
    print("Tableau title2: \(self.bookTitle)\n")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track. But I still don't have anything in my array.

Comment: This should work. Note that I've made some modifications from your version. Could you please tell me the exact result of `print("Tableau title2: \(self.bookTitle)\n")` when you run this code?

Comment: Sorry yes it's working. Except the dispatch_async what did you change ?

Comment: You were redeclaring the `collectionView` before using it. Not sure if it was an *error* but it was certainly unnecessary so I removed it. :) Anyway, I'm glad I was able to help and that it's working now, cool.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je dois aller voir la doc sur la gestion des threads ;)