# parse containedIn query returns nothing

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

The following are my codes:

```
var food = [chicken, fish, duck, pork]

var recipeNames = [String]()
var recipePictures = [UIImage]()


func getRecipes() {

    let getRecipesQuery = PFQuery(className: "recipes")

    getRecipesQuery.whereKey("food", containedIn: food)

    getRecipesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (recipes, error) -> Void in

        if let recipes = recipes {

            self.recipeNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.recipePictures.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for recipe in recipes {

                self.recipeNames.append(recipe["name"] as! String)

                if let recipePictureFile = recipe["pictureFile"] as? PFFile {

                    recipePictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {

                            if let picture = UIImage(data: imageData!) {

                                self.recipePictures.append(picture)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        print(self.recipeNames.count)

        print(self.recipePictures.count)
    }
}
```

I printed the two arrays counts at the end to check if anything is fetched, the counts are both 0. Any idea why this is happening? There are definitely objects in the class which keys "food" equal to one of the objects in the "food" array, thanks!

**EDIT**

```
func getRecipes() {

    let getRecipesQuery = PFQuery(className: "recipes")

    getRecipesQuery.whereKey("food", containedIn: food)

    getRecipesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (recipes, error) -> Void in

        if let recipes = recipes {

            self.recipeNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.recipePictures.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for recipe in recipes {

                self.recipeNames.append(recipe["name"] as! String)

                if let recipePictureFile = recipe["pictureFile"] as? PFFile {

                    recipePictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {

                            if let picture = UIImage(data: imageData!) {

                                self.recipePictures.append(picture)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.recipesTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Similar* issue solved here, you can apply the same solutions to your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36087900/2227743

Comment: @Eric D. i modified my codes like the edit above but i'm still getting array index out of range error? or have i misunderstood what the link is suggesting? thanks

Comment: Looks like to me that you *did* understand the issue and the solution. :) But now you have a *different* error which requires further debugging: you're accessing an index which is not part of the array. Like when an array has only one element and you try to access a second element.

Comment: @Eric D. i tried printing the arrays counts inside dispatch_async but its still returning 0... I'm actually a bit uncertain about the containedIn function that I'm using, not sure if thats the correct way to query an array... or sth else might be wrong, any idea?

Comment: I didn't notice before that you have *a closure inside a closure* (getDataInBackgroundWithBlock inside findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock). It means that your reloadData is still outside the scope of when the array is populated and you see the result before its populated. Try put the dispatch inside the most inner closure.

Comment: @EricD. I put reload data together with print in the inner most closure right after I append picture into the array, this time nothing is printed in the logs and I'm still getting out of range error... gosh this is hard

Comment: `nothing is printed in the logs` It would mean there's no more errors, I believe. ;) The fact you get `out of range error` is now an issue on the other side, where you access the array: the array is empty but you force retrieve data from one of its indexes. // As for *why* the array is empty, I'm afraid I can't help you further since I don't have access to your backend.

Comment: @EricD. thanks for bearing with me! your suggestions are real helpful :)